# How do I reset the activeIndex in fotorama?

Tags: fotorama

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link  href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.6.0/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.6.0/fotorama.js"></script>

<div class="fotorama">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
</div>
```

With the above, if I want to replace the image carousel with a new set of images E.g. 3 and 4, I'd destroy fotorama, replace the images, then turn fotorama on again.

```
var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();

// 2. Get the API object.
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

fotorama.destroy();

$('.fotorama').html('<img src="http://s.fotorama.io/3.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/4.jpg">');

// 3. Turn it on again.
$('.fotorama').fotorama();
```

This seems to work well just that fotorama remembers what the index position of the image I was browsing. E.g. in the original image carousel, I went from the first image to the second, which means the activeIndex is now 1, then I destroy fotorama, and create a new one with images 3, and 4 as shown in the code, when the carousel's activated the index starts from 1 instead of 0 and I'm viewing image 4. I know that this information is stored in activeIndex, but even when I set that to 0 before destroying the original fotorama the new fotorama doesn't start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use API functionality to load new images and to go back to the first image:

```
// Load new images
fotorama.load([
  {img: '1.jpg', thumb: '1-thumb.jpg'},
  {img: '2.jpg', thumb: '2-thumb.jpg'}
]);

// Go to the first image
fotorama.show(0);
```

More information in regard to the API and options can be found here: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/